# Does fractal decomposition work with irreducible quartics and higher powers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am curious to know if one can write for example
$$\frac{5x}{(1-x)(x^4+1)^2}=\frac{A}{1-x} + \frac{Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx+1}{x^4+1} +  \frac{Ex^3+Fx^2+Gx+H}{(x^4+1)^2}$$
and more generally can one use this method for higher powers (for example if we had $(x^{10}+1)^2$) insead? I have used this method for cubics and parabolas but I have never seen it being used for higher powers. Any input would be greatly appriciated

Comment: $$\frac{5 x}{(1-x) \left(x^4+1\right)^2}=\frac{5 (x+1) \left(x^2+1\right)}{4 \left(x^4+1\right)}+\frac{5 \left(x^3+x^2+x-1\right)}{2 \left(x^4+1\right)^2}+\frac{5}{4 (1-x)}$$

Comment: Also $(x^2 + x \sqrt 2 + 1)( x^2 - x \sqrt 2 + 1) = x^4 + 1 $

Comment: Also, the word "fractal" does not belong here, even though it sounds like it does.

Comment: Eventually, you learn to leverage complex numbers, with respect to which every polynomial is conveniently the product of powers of linear factors. (If need be, you could take a temporary detour into the complex realm, do the standard decomposition there, and then return to reality by combining "conjugate" terms.) So, it's not really worth thinking too hard about fractional decompositions with respect to higher-power irreducible (over reals) polynomials.